# Можно ли убрать спулинг фразы "PL/SQL procedure successfully completed." и только её?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

Спулю в файл из PLSQL блока будущий скрипт на исполнение (своим генератором скриптов). В конце он приписывает эту фразу, что мешает сразу отправить скрипт на исполнение. Нужно зайти, удалить последние три строки (еще два переноса), и только тогда исполнить. Как это отключить? В шапке генератора сейчас:

```
set serveroutput on
set termout off
set serveroutput on size 1000000
set linesize 32767
set trim on
set trims on
spool scripts.sql
```

Comment: `set feedback off`, потом опять включить, если необходимо.

Comment: Благодарность испытываю. А то я уже костыль воткнул в виде батника, который очищает конец :)

Comment: Возможно вам пригодятся и другие настройки, которые обычно используют для создания SQL скриптов: http://ba6.us/?q=generate_scripts_with_sqlplus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Надо добавить до PL/SQL блока:

```
set feedback off
```

И опять включить, если для последующих команд скрипта нужен отклик:

```
set feedback on
```

PS почти все set параметры можно объединять и сокращать, например:

```
set lines 32767 pages 0 trim on feed off
```