# Вывод курсора из процедуры

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsql-developer

По аналогии с выводом результата функции:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(пакет.функция(параметры));
```

А что если у нас есть не функция, а процедура, где первый параметр - out sys_refcursor?

```
procedure My_proc
 (
  out_refcur  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
  другие In параметры
 )
```

Как получить так же выборку прямо в окне SQL Window, как в случае функции?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Возможно ли вывести результат запроса SELECT из PL/SQL блока?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1017093/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-select-%d0%b8%d0%b7-pl-sql-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В SQL Window нельзя напрямую вызвать процедуру. Перейдите в [Command Window](https://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev120.html) и попробуйте, например:

```sql
set autoprint on
col dummy for a10
variable rcur refcursor
declare
    procedure getCursor (rcur out sys_refcursor) is 
    begin
        open rcur for select dummy from dual;
    end;    
begin
    getCursor (:rcur); 
end;
/
```

Вывод:

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

DUMMY
----------
X
```

Если мешает сообщение о выполнении - [Как убрать фразу "PL/SQL procedure successfully completed."](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/923386/217579)

Answer (score 2):

В 12с у пакета dbms_sql появилась функция return_result.
Вам нужно указать в своей процедуре dbms_sql.return_result(_cur_name), т.е.

```
    create or replace My_proc(
      out_refcur in OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
      другие In параметры
      )
    is
    begin
    ....
    dbms_sql.return_result(out_refcur);
    end;
```

В итоге при вызове в sqlplus вам покажется содержимое курсора.
В 11g и ранние версии нужно создавать функцию.