# Возможно ли вывести результат запроса SELECT из PL/SQL блока?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Как можно получить результат `SELECT` из  PL/SQL блока так же, как и обычно в SQL?

Например, такой запрос:

```
SELECT foo, bar FROM foobar;
```

Пытаюсь выполнить:

```sql
BEGIN
    SELECT foo, bar FROM foobar;
END;
```

, но так не работает.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/351489/6571020

Answer (score 4):

Начиная с версии 12.1 стало возможным вывести неявный результат (см. [*Implicit Result Sets*](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NEWFT/chapter12101.htm#FEATURENO10020)):

```sql
declare
    rc sys_refcursor;
begin
    open rc for select * from dual;
    dbms_sql.return_result(rc);
end;
/
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

ResultSet #1

DUMMY
-----
X
```

В болле ранних версиях, в зависимости от используемого SQL инструмента, было возможно использовать подстановочную переменную, как в этом примере:

```sql
SQL> set autoprint on
SQL> var rc refcursor
    
begin
    open :rc for select * from dual;
end;
/
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

DUMMY
-----
X
```

<sub>Источник: [@WilliamRobertson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40360471/6571020)</sub>